# Générer ou engendrer?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> Dans *Driver 2*, l’algorithme du jeu en monde ouvert génère l’environnement (voitures, personnages, temps) au fur et à mesure que le joueur progresse.

> Dans *Driver 2*, l’algorithme du jeu en monde ouvert engendre l’environnement (voitures, personnages, temps) au fur et à mesure que le joueur progresse.

Si vous le voulez, vous pouvez repenser la phrase.

Edit: d’autres verbes qui me viennent à l’esprit: *faire apparaître, matérialiser, donner corps à, produire*

Comment: Génère semble définitivement être le mieux adapté: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9n%C3%A9ration_proc%C3%A9durale

Comment: Pour les autres verbes, le contexte, le public ciblé, l'action en cours et autres paramètres qui peuvent influencer les émotions ou la rigueur sont à prendre en compte.

Comment: Sinon, plus simple, *l'algorithme **crée** l'environnement*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le verbe « générer » a deux sens simplement définis, « engendrer » et « produire ». ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rer))

Le verbe « engendrer », dans son sens littéral signifie « provoquer la genèse de » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/engendrer)), une définitions qui couvre la description de deux catégories de phénomènes, ceux qui ont trait à la matière et ceux qui ont trait aux êtres vivants. Dans les deux cas le processus de provocation d'une genèse implique non pas une simple création mais un « don »  d'une partie de l'entité créatrice à l'entité créée. La matière engendre la vie qui est fondée sur une structure matérielle particulière ; le jus sucré du raisin engendre le vin par un « don » total du sucre à une transformation en alcool ; le bois engendre le feu ; la mère qui engendre donne d'elle même, son image, un peu de sa vie même. L'idée générale dans la création qui est impliquée semble être celle de la transmission d'un genre ( La forme a.fr. gendre s'explique prob. par l'infl. du verbe a.fr. gendrer (lat. class. generare « engendrer »)   ([TLFi, genre](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/genre)) par un don plus ou moins grand de ce qui constitue à l'entité qui engendre. Ce n'est pas le type de processus que l'on trouve dans cette création informatique ; la machine, ou programme reste intacte, n'est la cause finalement que de quelque chose qui est différent. Pour cette raison particulière,  en tant que verbe au sens littéral,  dans cette phrase j'exclurais « engendrer » et je choisirais « générer », ou même « produire », aussi bien que « créer ».

Remarquons que d'un point de vue  philosophique, qui ne peut pas être celui de la simple description que fournit la phrase, « engendre » dans son sens métaphorique et figuré apporte une idée nouvelle (1. [Le compl. d'obj. dir. désigne une chose concr.] Donner forme, consistance, réalité (à quelque chose).) ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/engendrer)). Les codes engendrent les voitures, les personnages, etc.

Answer (score 2):

*Générer* est sans aucun doute le mot le plus approprié dans un contexte de jeux vidéo (et d'informatique en général).

Le terme *engendrer* est trop littéraire, je ne l'ai jamais entendu dans ce contexte.

*Créer* peut se rencontrer aussi, mais il est plus ambigu. *Générer* sous-entend aussi que c'est fait de manière automatique. Si on parle de "*création des personnages*" par exemple, on aurait tendance à comprendre qu'on parle de design, et un humain en est à l'origine. Alors que la "*génération des personnages*" est forcément l'action du code du jeu.

Comment: Effectivement "création" semblerait plutôt faire allusion au processus créatif des concepteurs du jeux. "générer" correspond bien aussi à l'anglais "computer generated".

Comment: Je suis d'accord sur le sens général de créer mais dans la phrase *créé par l'algorithme au fur et à mesure que le joueur progresse*, une intervention manuelle humaine dans le processus de création me semble plus qu'improbable.

Comment: @jlliagre Bien sûr, *créé* peut être utilisé pour les deux, c'est pour ça que j'ai dit "ambigu". En contexte c'est clair mais sans précision ça peut être l'un ou l'autre.